# Java ignores EOF while reading chars from file

Tags: java

I try to read a File char by char. Unfortunately Java ignores EOF while reading chars from file.

```
FileReader fileReader = new FileReader(fileText);
char c;
String word = "";
List<String> words = new ArrayList<String>();

while ((c = (char) fileReader.read()) != -1) {
    System.out.println(c);
    if (c != ' ') {
        word = word + c;
    }
    else {
        words.add(word + " ");
        word = "";
    }
}
```

It should break up after the file is read, but instead it never stops running....

Comment: BufferedReader will read fewer times from the disk, and thus speed up a little. even if you loop over the characters one by one.

Comment: @irreputable That is the correct answer. You should post that as an answer. [Primitive Narrowing Conversion](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.3): `int` to `char` conversion discards all but the 16 lower bits. Java represents numbers in 2's complement. And the 2's complement of -1 is 11111... When you compare c == -1, you are doing widening conversion of char to int, then you compare ints; i.e. you "zero-extend the representation of the char value to fill the wider format" i.e. replace the 1's you previously lost with 0's. Thus you get false.

Comment: @ignis it is not 100% correct, since a file may contain a FFFF char, though it shouldn't.

Comment: I disagree - "[The value FFFF is guaranteed not to be a Unicode character at all.](http://www.unicode.org/charts/PDF/UFFF0.pdf)"

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In Java, `char` is unsigned and cannot equal `-1`. You should do the comparison before you do the cast.

```
int ch;
while ((ch = fileReader.read()) != -1) {
    char c = (char)ch;
    System.out.println(c);
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 4):

This happens because `char` cannot be equal to `-1`, even if you assign `-1` to it:

```
char c = (char)-1;
System.out.println(c == -1); // prints false
```

Make `c` an `int`, and cast it to `char` only when you concatenate:

```
word = word + (char)c;
```

Better yet, use `StringBuilder` to build strings at runtime: otherwise, you create lots of temporary string objects in a loop, and these objects get thrown away.

```
StringBuilder word = new StringBuilder();
List<String> words = new ArrayList<String>();
int c;
while ((c = fileReader.read()) != -1) {
    System.out.println((char)c);
    word.append((char)c);
    if (c == ' ') {
        words.add(word.toString());
        word = new StringBuilder();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You should try the below code

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    FileReader fileReader = new FileReader(fileLocation);
    int c;
    String word = "";
    List<String> words = new ArrayList<String>();

    while ((c = (int) fileReader.read()) != -1) {
        System.out.println((char)c);
        char ch = (char)c;
        if (ch != ' ') {
            word = word + ch;
        } else {
            words.add(word + " ");
            word = "";
        }
    }
    System.out.println(word);
}
```

Comment: I think you need to cast `c` to a `char` before adding it to `word`, otherwise it will concatenate the string version of the number stored in `c`.

Comment: @jonhopkins Thanks for the suggestion, updated my post according to your suggestion. You were right.